# NodeJS - Unable to load NPM "joystick-controller" library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, joystick

I post today this problem because no answer could help me, I devloppe a web server that will be used to control motor for a robot. my problem here is that the server (under nodeJS) loads the html file but not the 'joystick-controller.js' script unless load with a url.
I also tried to install the dependency "joystick-controller" with NPM but I can not use it server side. The problem here is that my server will not connect to the internet.
I put my code below

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JoyStick</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html,
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .world {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            outline: none;
        }

        .info {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            top: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap: 10px;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            font-size: smaller;
            user-select: none;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .right {
            right: 10px;
        }

        .left {
            left: 10px;
        }

        .link {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 50%;
            transform: translateX(50%);
            color: #8a1c09;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
    <style id="style-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq">
        .joystick-container-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: fixed;
            outline: none;
            right: 20%;
            bottom: 20%;
            transform: translate(50%, 50%);
        }
    
        .joystick-controller-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.5;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: relative;
            outline: 2px solid #4c4c4c77;
            background: radial-gradient(circle,#ebebeb55, #5c5c5c55);
        }
    
        .joystick-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            position: absolute;
            cursor: grab;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
            background: radial-gradient(#000c, #3e3f46aa);
            transition: border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
        </style></head>

<body>
    <div class="info right">
        <p>X: <span id="x2">0</span></p>
        <p>Y: <span id="y2">0</span></p>
        <p>X Leveled: <span id="xLeveled2">0</span></p>
        <p>Y Leveled: <span id="yLeveled2">0</span></p>
        <p>Distance: <span id="distance2">0</span></p>
        <p>Angle: <span id="angle2">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.statically.io/gh/cyrus2281/joystick-controller/main/dist/umd/joystick-controller.min.js">
    </script>-->
        
    <script type="module">
        // uncomment for dev. (the CDN uses the global import, no need for module import)
        // import JoystickController from '../src/joystick-controller.js';

        const x2 = document.querySelector("#x2");
        const y2 = document.querySelector("#y2");
        const xLeveled2 = document.querySelector("#xLeveled2");
        const yLeveled2 = document.querySelector("#yLeveled2");
        const distance2 = document.querySelector("#distance2");
        const angle2 = document.querySelector("#angle2");

        window.joystickHandlers = {
            leftJoystickHandler: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            rightJoystickHandler: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
        }

        const rightJoystick = new JoystickController({
                x: "20%",
                y: "20%",
                leftToRight: false,
                opacity: 0.5,
                maxRange: 100,
                joystickClass: "joystick",
                distortion: true,
            },
            (data) => {
                x2.innerHTML = data.x;
                y2.innerHTML = data.y;
                xLeveled2.innerHTML = data.leveledX;
                yLeveled2.innerHTML = data.leveledY;
                distance2.innerHTML = data.distance;
                angle2.innerHTML = data.angle;
                window.joystickHandlers.rightJoystickHandler.x = data.leveledX
                window.joystickHandlers.rightJoystickHandler.y = data.leveledY
            }
        );
    </script>


<div id="joystick-container-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m" class="joystick-container-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m "><div id="joystick-controller-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m" class="joystick-controller-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m "><div id="joystick-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m" class="joystick-iw7mcfl3ofhovoyeu6kn9m joystick" style="left: 70px; bottom: 70px; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; cursor: grab;"></div></div></div>
<div id="joystick-container-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq" class="joystick-container-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq "><div id="joystick-controller-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq" class="joystick-controller-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq "><div id="joystick-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq" class="joystick-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq joystick" style="left: 50px; bottom: 50px; border-radius: 50%; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; cursor: grab; transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(3.5423rad);"></div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
const express = require('express')
const jc = require('joystick-controller')
const fs = require('fs')

/*
var joy0 = new jc(
    {
      maxRange: 70,
      level: 10,
      radius: 50,
      joystickRadius: 30,
      opacity: 0.5,
      leftToRight: false,
      bottomToUp: true,
      containerClass: "joystick-container",
      controllerClass: "joystick-controller",
      joystickClass: "joystick",
      distortion: true,
      x: "25%",
      y: "25%",
    },
    ({ x, y, leveledX, leveledY, distance, angle }) =>
      console.log(x, y, leveledX, leveledY, distance, angle)
  );
  */


const app = express()
const port = 8000

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    //res.send("<div id='joystick-container-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq' class='joystick-container-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq '><div id='joystick-controller-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq' class='joystick-controller-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq '><div id='joystick-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq' class='joystick-p2pxmw28d2r0xgi3z111pzq joystick' style='left: 50px; bottom: 50px; border-radius: 50%; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; cursor: grab; transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(3.5423rad);'></div></div></div>")
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
    fs.readFile('./index.html',null,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            res.end('fill have error')
        }else{
            res.end(data)
        }
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log('app start on : http://localhost:'+port))
```